# how do I get yesod-persistent to recognize the type of my aeson parsed entity array?

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent, aeson

I've got a yesod handler that can accept some json with an array of objects.
I'd like to insert all the objects into the database.

```
newtype NodeList = NodeList [Node]

instance FromJSON NodeList where
    parseJSON (Object o) = NodeList <$> o .: "nodes"
    parseJSON _ = mzero

postMoreNodesR :: Handler ()
postMoreNodesR = do
        nodes::NodeList <- requireJsonBody
        runDB $ mapM_ insert nodes
        return ()
```

But some how, its not recognizing my entity type. (although other POST and GET handlers in the same module work great.) I can tell I'm pretty close, but I'm not sure what to do, since "a0" is not a type I've declared anywhere. Here's the error:

```
Handler/Node.hs:46:30:
    Couldn't match expected type `[a0]' with actual type `NodeList'
    In the second argument of `mapM_', namely `nodes'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `mapM_ insert nodes'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: runDB $ mapM_ insert nodes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also pattern match directly in the bind:

```
postMoreNodesR :: Handler ()
postMoreNodesR = do
  NodeList nodes <- requireJsonBody

  runDB $ mapM_ insert nodes

  return ()
```

This obviates the need for the type annotation as well.

It works because the do expression is de-sugared to a lambda:

```
requireJsonBody >>= \NodeList nodes -> runDB -- ...
```

Comment: even nicer! I didn't know you could pattern match inside a do block.

Comment: It's not actually de-sugared to a lambda. It's more complex than that, thanks to `fail`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! I followed the types and realized I needed a helper function to extract the Nodes from the newtyped NodeList:

```
getNodesFromList :: NodeList -> [Node]
getNodesFromList (NodeList l) = l
```

Then my handler function became:

```
postMoreNodesR :: Handler ()
postMoreNodesR = do
        nodes::NodeList <- requireJsonBody
        runDB $ mapM_ insert $ getNodesFromList nodes
        return ()
```

This stuff is really starting to click!

Comment: actually, Haskell can generate that function for you automatically :)

Comment: `data NodeList = NodeList { getNodesFromList :: [Node] }`